# how to export zh_CN.utf8 in Arch liveCD environment?

Tags: arch-linux, locale

After i typed `locale -a` it showed only `c, en_US.utf8, POSIX`, then how to export zh_CN.utf8?
Cause I've to use a software, which uses zh_CN, to connect the Internet during installation progress...
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Arch Wiki has a [Locale page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale).

Essentially, you first have to enable a specific locale by uncommenting the name of the locale in the file `/etc/locale.gen`

Then update the list with `# locale-gen`

To define the system-wide locale used on the system, add the specified locale to the `/etc/rc.conf file`

Comment: thx for your answer, but it seems there're still some other problems... anyway, thanks :)